# reactjs -- this.props being empty in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I've seen many posts regarding `this.props`, but none of them seems to answer my question, or at least I couldn't find it.

My component uses `this.props` as args to get my url

This following code is almost the exact copy of https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let entityKey = this.props.eKey;
    fetch(`some/url/${this.props.eKey}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading My List...</div>;
    } else {
      if (!items) {
        return <div>Failed to Load My List</div>;
      } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>
              {item}
            </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      );
      }
    }
  }
}



export default MyList
```

Now my script that calls this is simply

```
class MyFunc extends Component {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyList
        eKey={this.props.eKey}
      />
    </dev>
  );
}
```

I eliminated other code in `MyFunc` for simplicity

When I `console.log` my `this.props` inside `MyList`, it returns `{eKey: ""}`, so I know that the `eKey` is being passed in. However, as you can see, it's empty.

I don't know if it's because I have this at the `componentDidMount` cycle which for some reason `this.props` hasn't arrived when `fetch`ing. If that's the case, how do I guarantee the arrival before executing that line?

If it's somewhere else where I have issue, what went wrong?

**EDIT:**

To add in some more info. This is tied to a reducer. The redux is not exactly my strong suite.....so please correct me on any concept that's wrong.

The reducer takes the `initialState` and an `action`. The action can be different things. The only place that `eKey` is loaded is when `action.type='load'`

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD:
        return {
          ...state,
          eKey: action.data.eKey,
          // and some other stuff
        };

    // some other cases here

    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Interesting thing is there's a submit button that updates another component, which supposedly get a new `eKey` and get the eKey's data. At that time, the eKey is always populated, but my `myList` is not updated accordingly. I think it's another issue I have to figure out, but just wanna put it out here in case it's somehow related.

It seems like the reducer is not called only the component is mounted and `componentDidMount` is already called. And `MyList` does not update when the reducer is finally called. I'm not sure how to solve this problem

**EDIT 2:**

I tried moving what's inside `componentDidMount` into the `render` function (with some mod, of course). Does it work? sure, but when I `console.log` something, it just continues to print out stuff. Seems like this render function is constantly receiving update. I'm not sure if this is normal as my reactjs knowledge is not enough to answer this question. It works, but I'm wondering if this is the right way to do things

Comment: can you check in MyFunc if this.props.eKey is present there or not. It can be a reason eKey is empty in MyList

Comment: @MohitTilwani I also put console.log in `MyList` as well and found that at the time when `MyList` is called, `this.props.eKey` is empty, but later on it was loaded and has correctly printed out the eKey I was looking for. So timing is the issue at the end? Should I not call it at `componentDidMount`? It's not `ComponetWillMount`, sorry for the typo

Comment: How is eKey passed down to your MyFunc component?

Comment: Timing issue could be possible if getting eKey (from wherever it is originated) is asynchronous. If you could provide some more details like MyFunc code and the code of the component using MyFunc, i can help you more

Comment: I believe there's a reducer in the play as well. The initialState is set in the reducer.js. `eKey` is empty at the time. eKey is loaded based on `action` which triggers a `switch case`. the eKey is only assigned in one of those cases. It's kinda hard to explain it here. I'll add more context to the main post

Comment: What is the initial value of `eKey` in your reducer?

Comment: @peetya it's an empty string

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by calling another function, so my code looks like

```
class MyList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadMystuff().then(() => {
      if (this.state.eKey !== this.props.eKey) {
        let eKey = this.props.eKey;
        this.fetchSList(eKey);
      }
    }).catch((error) => toast(error.message));
  }

  fetchSList(eKey) {
    if (eKey !== '') {
      fetch(`some_api_url_config/${this.props.entityKey}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
              (result) => {
                this.setState({
                  isLoaded: true,
                  items: result
              });
            },
            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
              });
            }
          );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (items) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>S List</h3>
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
              <li key={item}>
                {item}
              </li>
              ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (error) {
      return <div>Error: List Missing...{error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading List...</div>;
    } else {
        return <div>Not Found</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `loadMyStuff` is the one retrieving the eKey, so calling that will effectively get me the eKey to resolve the timing issue